# How to copy files from local file system to HDFS file system?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I have installed hadoop on Ubuntu 14.04. I am getting the following error whenever I copy files from the local file system to HDFS.

I am using this command:

```
/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg
```

And the error I am experiencing is:

```
/usr/local/hadoop$: No such file or directory
```

I am newbie to Linux environment. I could not understand which file is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg
```

I think you had a typo in your command.

Comment: When I remove $, I am getting this reply from the terminal,   location name: is a directory

Comment: You need not just to remove the $ sign, but also remove the spaces around so it will be like: `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop`